# Entry's are showing default text instead of showing placeholder Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

When I run the app, on first up page instead `Entry`s are showing default text  `0` instead of placeholder.

I have `AddContactPage.xaml`

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Class" Text="{Binding Class}"></Entry>
    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Id" Text="{Binding StudentId}"></Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

Attributes binded to Entries

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public int Class { get; set; }
```

How can I solve this issue. See o/p-

[image]

Comment: Entry control set Text, not Int, therefore you are not able to see the placeholder. Change your StudentId  & Class string then it will work.

Comment: @kk - Thank you for pointing this out. However I had this idea in mind. But I thought if there is any another way without changing data types. If we change change data types it would another kind of heck, not for few fields if we have multiple.

Comment: I don't know of any other way but to use a String Property for this.. You can keep your current properties and add a `string` property (`ClassString` and `StudentIdString`) with only a getter which casts `Class` or `StudentId` to a `string`. Don't forget to call `RaisePropertyChanged("ClassString")` in the `Class` Property.

Comment: @DennisSchröer - Thanks for your suggestion seems difficult but worth implementing.

Comment: Use Converter. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is a string property for binding:

```
private int _studentId;

public int StudentId 
{ 
    get { return _studentId; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _studentId, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("StudentIdString"); // If you're using Prism. You can use any other way to raise the PropertyChanged event 
    }
}

public string StudentIdString
{
    get { return StudentId.ToString(); }
}
```

That's it! Now you can bind `StudentIdString` to your `Entry`. Do the same with `Class` and you're good to go.

---

Another solution to your problem is a converter as Woj suggested:

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int i = (int)value;
        return i.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return int.Parse((string)value);
    }
}
```

Then use it in your xaml like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntToStringConverter x:Key="intToString" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Entry Placeholder="Enter Id" Text="{Binding StudentId, Converter={StaticResource intToString}}"></Entry>
```

Comment: Whare `IntToStringConverter.cs` should be located?

Comment: @Arvindraja it doesn't matter, just put it somewhere where you think it makes sense. I like to have a folder named "Converters" where I save all my Converter classes

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use StringFormat. Try this
StringFormat='{0:#.##;;}'

Answer (score 0):

Since the Entry control Text is binded to a model, it will not show a place holder for a null property which is associated. You may need to remove the Text binding in that case.